# fail handled in the wrong monad

Tags: haskell

At least I think that's what's going on.

Main.hs:

```
module Main (
    main
) where

import Arithmetic
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Either
import Control.Monad.Error

testExpr :: Expr Float
testExpr = 
        (MultExpr "*"
            (AddExpr "XXX"
                (NumExpr 1) 
                (AddExpr "-"
                    (NumExpr 24)
                    (NumExpr 21)
                )
            ) 
            (NumExpr 5) 
        )

main :: IO ()
main = do 
    putStrLn $ case eval testExpr of
            Left msg -> "Error: " ++ msg
            Right result -> show result
```

Arithmetic.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

module Arithmetic  where

type Op = String

data Expr a where
    NumExpr :: Float -> Expr Float
    AddExpr :: Op -> Expr Float -> Expr Float -> Expr Float
    MultExpr :: Op -> Expr Float -> Expr Float -> Expr Float

eval :: (Monad m) => Expr Float -> m Float
eval (NumExpr n) = return n
eval (AddExpr "+" e1 e2) = evalBin (+) e1 e2
eval (AddExpr "-" e1 e2) = evalBin (-) e1 e2
eval (AddExpr "%" e1 e2) = evalBin (%) e1 e2
eval (AddExpr _ _ _ ) = fail "Invalid operator. Expected +, - or %"
eval (MultExpr "*" e1 e2) = evalBin (*) e1 e2
eval (MultExpr "/" e1 e2) = evalBin (/) e1 e2
eval (MultExpr _ _ _ ) = fail "Invalid operator. Expected * or /"

evalBin :: (Monad m) => (Float -> Float -> Float) -> Expr Float -> Expr Float -> m Float
evalBin op e1 e2 = do 
  v1 <- eval e1
  v2 <- eval e2
  return $ op v1 v2

infixl 6 %
(%) :: Float -> Float -> Float
a % b = a - b * (fromIntegral $ floor (a / b))
```

But, when `eval` fails, I get an error in IO, without the "Error: " string appended.

Comment: That isn't possible with the code you've presented here; `eval testExpr` is evaluated in the `Either` monad, and never gets near `IO`. Something must be wrong with the code you've omitted; for instance, another part of your evaluation code may be calling `error` directly or indirectly, which bubbles up as an IO exception.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the post with full code

Comment: Turns out the problem was visible in the original code, too, I just missed it; I've posted a fix :)

Comment: ...and then fixed my fix :/ I misread some instances in mtl's documentation. It's fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of `base` are you using? `fail` is no longer defined to return a `Left` in [the latest version of the `Either e` monad](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Control-Monad-Instances.html), instead it uses the default definition ([which calls `error`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-Base.html#Monad), which throws an exception that can only be caught in IO).

I don't know why this changed.

Comment: Base-4.3.1.0. That would definitely explain it, as I just updated to the latest Haskell Platform.   If that's the case, what should I use instead of Either?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I see the problem now!

You are importing [Control.Monad.Error](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Error.html), but using the `Either` monad, whose `fail` definition calls `error` rather than returning `Left`.

What you need to do is change `eval testExpr` to `runIdentity . runErrorT $ eval testExpr`. You'll need to import `Data.Functor.Identity`.

In an old version of the mtl (monad transformer library), Either's `fail` method did indeed return `Left`. However, the problem is that this only allowed `Either e` to be a monad when `e` was an instance of the `Error` class. I believe this was considered especially undesirable because `fail` is generally thought to be a mistake; many people think that it should be moved out of the Monad typeclass.

You could of course opt for a different method of error handling entirely, but this is the closest analogue to what you already have that works with the newest versions of the libraries.

I would suggest you specialise your code in the Arithmetic module to use `ErrorT` and `throwError` directly; as a bonus, this will also let you catch the errors you throw within your interpreter.

You could also define your own error type, and in that case I suggest defining your own monad that uses Either:

```
newtype Eval a = Eval { runEval :: Either EvalError a }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

evalError :: EvalError -> Eval a
evalError e = Eval (Left e)
```

Either's monad instance will work just fine here; the only thing that has changed is its definition of `fail`. Note that you'll need the `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` extension to derive those instances.

You could of course use String instead of EvalError here, but that offers no benefits over a simple `ErrorT`; the advantage with using your own monad with a custom error type is that you don't have to define an instance of `Error`, which would require defining a "catch-all" error value for `noMsg`/`strMsg`.

Comment: Thanks. This isn't really serious code, but I'm trying to do things "well" as I learn, and there's something that seems good about using the generic `fail` in a "library" and deciding on the implementation where it's used. Is there any problem with just making my own error monad for the purpose? like this:  http://hpaste.org/55436 .

Comment: `Uncertain` is just `ErrorT Identity String`, which is what my answer uses `eval` with (instead of the Either monad). In general, I wouldn't bother making code like this generic; it can easily be adapted to run in other monads if it needs to be, even with a concrete monad; it's usually clearer to define a single, canonical monadic stack, rather than just layering typeclasses on as you need them.

Comment: `fail` is disliked because it can't be defined sensibly for the majority of monads, and isn't part of the mathematical *definition* of a monad. It is only in the Monad typeclass so that you can say `do { Right x <- m; ... }` and get an error message if the pattern-match fails; in an older version of Haskell, this added a MonadZero constraint too, but Haskell 98 baked `fail` right into Monad, ostensibly to make the language simpler for beginners, who might not understand why such non-total pattern-matching in a `do` block forced them to add constraints to their type.

Comment: I don't think that's a very good argument, but I'm not on the committee. `ErrorT` definitely sounds like the thing to use here; you might even want to define your own error type, which would allow you to handle errors programmatically without comparing strings; you'd just need to make it an instance of the `Error` typeclass.

Comment: I've expanded my answer along those lines.